# what security impact can be caused by injection of meta tags

Tags: web-application

when i added a header
X-Forwarded-Host: bing.com
it inject meta tags in the site containing bing.com does this have any security impact

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://bing.com/argentina"/>
```

can we inject XSS in it?
shall i report for this vulnerability?

shall i put an XSS payload or try redirection or what shall i do?

i have already tried to search in many websites for answer but i couldn't find any

Answer (score 1):

Some meta tags like property og:image can have JavaScript in the property so you can steal cookies or redirect a user or many other Xss attacks

Meta refresh tags can also take a victim to a phishing page that spoofs the real one